# Run node.js and mongodb in Godaddy hosting

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've installed nodejs and mongo db in a godaddy server (linux), and my node application is configured to run with port 8080. But unlike in Amazone servers, I see a place to configure ports in godaddy. anyway I can run the application with `npm start` but the application is not up and running. Could someone explain:

- Do I need to run the node app in "public_html" folder?
- How do I configure the server to run the app on a specific port(or
  should I    use port 80?)
- I tried to connect to the mongoDB `mongodb://163.10.70.33:27017/DB_NAME`. But I can't connect with this url.

Answer (score 1):

How to install Node app in CPanel of GoDaddy?

### I had a perfect article that I wrote about run node js application in cpanel and godaddy hosting.

https://medium.com/@cs5129606/how-to-install-node-app-in-cpanel-of-godaddy-46cbfff99d73

### You would need to create .htaccess file and make those change.

```
cd ~/public_html
nano .htaccess
```

### Copy information below, (3000) is the default port for express, change whatever port that you are going to setup

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Once your finish your installation, go to express site to copy some of the startup code:

```
mkdir myapp
cd myapp
npm init -y
npm install express --save
touch index.js
```

Don't forget to copy this code to your index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

### Now you are almost compete everything.

All you need is to make the server run all the time and no matter it crash or update

### install the forever start package on your server

```
npm i pm2 -g
```

### since the pm2 is very handy tool, you just run this command to run the server and restart by adding - watch tag

```
pm2 start index.js --watch
```

Comment: This comment is really very helpful. I am getting ng2 library to run node js and mongo db on godaddy shared hosting server

Comment: I'm glad that works. I had test pm2 if you have any log issue, you can run `pm2 logs` to see all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put all your files in the public_html folder. I'm not sure exactly which hosting plan but I have web hosting with cPanel (through GoDaddy).

I'm sure you've noticed that there are default files in the public_html folder. You can (and must) delete those and replace it with all your files.

Now, if you installed node and mongodb properly, everything should render properly.